# Как объявить функцию, которая будут принимать хэндлер, аналогичный асинхронным функциям boost.asio?

Tags: c++, boost, callback, асинхронность, boost.asio

Я хочу написать метод, который будет инкопсулировать в себе некоторую логику работы с boost.Asio, но чтоб в этот метод можно было передать хэндлер, который, внутри метода, можно передать в асинхронную функцию boost asio(async_accept, async_send...).

Ниже приблизительный пример.

```
class Server{
   ...
   void StartAccept(... handler){
        ...
        acceptor.async_accept(socket, handler)
        ...
   }
   ...
}
```

Как я понял, async_accept принимает шаблонный тип, следовательно нужно ввести шалон, но какого плана и как. Иными словами, какого типа должен быть handler?

Comment: В [Документации](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/master/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_socket_acceptor/async_accept.html) указано 8 вариантов

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как уже заметил в комментарии [@MaximTimakov](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/209264/maxim-timakov), в документации описаны все 8 перегрузок данного метода и, конечно же, все типы, которые они принимают. Чтобы было проще, кликайте *more...* в описании перегрузки и там смотрите на раздел *Example*. В нём как раз показано, какого типа должен быть handler.

Если брать самый простой вариант (первую перегрузку), то handler должен быть указателем на функцию, возвращающую `void` и принимающую `const boost::system::error_code&`, то есть для Вашего примера это будет выглядеть так:

```cpp
class Server{
   ...
   void StartAccept(... void (*handler)(const boost::system::error_code&)){
        ...
        acceptor.async_accept(socket, handler)
        ...
   }
   ...
}
```

Comment: А почему тогда мы можем передать туда параметр с любым количеством аргументов?? Или нмли мы применчем бинд, количество аргументов сокрпщается???

Comment: @DenverToha, Именно. Применение `std::bind` или `boost::bind`, позволяет передавать любое кол-во аргументов.